# a innerHTML alternative for a dom node

Tags: javascript

```
var ele = iframe_container[i];
var iframe_element = document.createElement("IFRAME");
```

How do I make `iframe_element` the only child of `ele`?.

I have tried `appendChild` and `replaceChild` but both are for a different purpose. What is the right way to do?.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Just use `innerHTML` when appropriate. In the absence of a single method to clear an element's children, it gets the point across the best.

Comment: Also. `innerHTML` is way faster then DOM manipulation. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest and the fastest way is.

```
ele.innerHTML = ''
ele.appendChild(iframe_element);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all childs then add yours.

```
while (ele.firstChild) ele.removeChild(ele.firstChild);
ele.appendChild(iframe_element);
```

Comment: how is innerHTML='' with appendchild

Comment: It should be faster to use `ele.innerHTML = ''` to remove all child nodes. And then use `appendChild` to insert your `iframe` into the container.

Comment: @MaratTanalin It would be faster to use `innerHTML` for both operations :-)

Comment: @Bart Sure, but `iframe` element could already exist when it should be inserted into a container.

Comment: I can hardly measure any perceivable difference on jsperf, but on average innerHTML has an infintesimal edge: http://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-empty-and-appendchild

Answer (score 1):

You could do this

HTML

```
<div id="something">Has content <span>you don't want</span></div>
```

Javascript

```
function emptyNode(node) {
    while (node.firstChild) {
        node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
    }
}

function innerHTML(node, newNode) {
    emptyNode(node);
    node.appendChild(newNode);
}

var ele = document.getElementById("something");
var iframe_element = document.createElement("IFRAME");

innerHTML(ele, iframe_element);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Ccujx/)

Note: @dystroy was faster than me.